# Issue with Gitlab - Projects scheduled for deletion but never deleted

Tags: gitlab

We've been using Gitlab on my current job for a while now, and have encountered some instability which express itself in various ways.

The most recent one: p**rojects that should be deleted are flagged as such but actual deletion never occurs.**

Some research has allowed me to see the probable cause of the problem, but not how to resolve it: the **ProjectDestroyWorker** hasn't run for over 10 days.

Could someone point me to some documentation on the mechanism(s) that trigger the workers, and how to monitor them?

Version: GitLab Community Edition 8.5.0 a513e09

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues with this kind of problem: [issue 15334](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/15334), [issue 20984](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/20984).
Checking the backtrace from `sidekiq.log` can help

Merge Requests [5695](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/5695) and [4341](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/4341) (for GitLab 8.11) should fix some of those issues, like:

> There is a race condition in DestroyGroupService now that projects are deleted asynchronously:
>
> - User attempts to delete group
> - `DestroyGroupService` iterates through all projects and schedules a Sidekiq job to delete each Project
> - `DestroyGroupService` destroys the `Group`, leaving all its projects without a namespace
> - `Projects::DestroyService` runs later but the can? (`current_user`, `:remove_project`) is false because the user no longer has permission to destroy projects with no namespace.
> - This leaves the project in pending_delete state with no namespace/group.

Comment: I actually found some information hinting at the destroy process in [issue 18875](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/18875), which is where the ProjectDestroyWorker notion comes from. I'd really like to get information on how to monitor the current state of the workers in gitlab, and possibly how to trigger their run. The extract you provided is of great interest, specifically the Project::DestroyService, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue during the migration to hashed storage in `v13.5.7`

- [Drop to the ruby console & destroy projects that are pending
  deletion](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/troubleshooting/gitlab_rails_cheat_sheet.html#find-projects-that-are-pending-deletion)

In my particular case this allowed `gitlab-rake gitlab:storage:legacy_projects` to correctly show `0` so further upgrades were possible.